# How to disable date field in Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I would  like to use Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker Version 4 for my project.

The requirement is to find a time range. My question is :
- is it possible to have range between 2 time without the date (in other word, disable the date and only have the time range).

Your help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use the component as a timepicker using [`format: HH:mm`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format). You can limit selectable time using [disabledTimeIntervals](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals). Anyway you should edit  your question adding your code to show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the component as a timepicker using [`format: HH:mm`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format). You can limit selectable time using [`disabledTimeIntervals`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals).

Here a working example disabling time from 0 to 8 and from 15 to 18:

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })],
    [moment({ h: 15 }), moment({ h: 18 })]
  ],
  defaultDate: moment("12:00", 'HH:mm'),
  format: 'HH:mm'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h6>datetimepicker</h6>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker"/>
  </div>
</div>
```